# How to set default values for a lead() column, per 'partition by' and then 'order by'

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I need to derive a 'tf' column by partitioning results by scid & dbid, so from [ my experimentation is here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f14ef/3 ]

```
CREATE TABLE scdbs (
  "dbid" bigint, 
  "scid" bigint,
  "version" character varying(128),
  "t0" bigint
);

INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (2, 14, '1.1', 0);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (3, 6, '13.3a', 0);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (4, 5, '13.3a', 0);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (5, 8, '13.3a', 0);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (6, 7, '13.3a', 0);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (7, 5, '14.0a', 1462820400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (8, 6, '14.0a', 1462820400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (9, 7, '14.0a', 1462820400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (10, 8, '14.0a', 1462820400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (11, 5, '14.0b', 2093972400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (12, 6, '14.0b', 2093972400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (13, 7, '14.0b', 2093972400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (14, 8, '14.0b', 2093972400000);
INSERT INTO scdbs VALUES (17, 3, '1.0', 0);
```

I want to return this:

```
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
scid  | dbid | version   |    t0         |  tf   
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    3 |   14 | 1.0       |             0 | 9999999999999  <= dflt value
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    5 |    3 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    5 |    8 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    5 |   13 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 | 9999999999999  <= dflt value
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    6 |    4 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    6 |    6 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    6 |   12 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 | 9999999999999  <= dflt value
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    7 |    5 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    7 |    9 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    7 |   10 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 | 9999999999999  <= dflt value
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    8 |    2 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    8 |    7 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    8 |   11 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 | 9999999999999  <= dflt value
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
```

but using

```
SELECT
  scid,
  dbid,
  version,
  t0,
  lead(t0,1,9999999999999) over (order by scid,dbid) AS "tf" from scdbs;
```

but returns:

```
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
 scid | dbid | version   |    t0         |  tf   
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    3 |   14 | 1.0       |             0 |             0
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    5 |    3 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    5 |    8 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    5 |   13 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 |             0
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    6 |    4 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    6 |    6 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    6 |   12 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 |             0
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    7 |    5 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    7 |    9 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    7 |   10 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 |             0
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
    8 |    2 | 13.3a     |             0 | 1462820400000
    8 |    7 | 14.0a     | 1462820400000 | 2093972400000
    8 |   11 | 14.0b     | 2093972400000 | 9999999999999  <= dflt value             
------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `over (partition by scid order by dbid)`

Comment: And that works! Thank you @Abelisto I tried it here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f14ef/4

Comment: @Abelisto Why don't you post as answer? There are quite a few unanswered questions in which you provide a correct answer in the comments.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Frequently I just dont know what I can to add to the few-words comment except the link to the official documentation. The PostgreSQL section in the documentation here is a poor